# How to accelerate a for loop on model.fit()?

Tags: python, loops, keras, neural-network

I am using model.fit() to train a neural network (of two layers) on a dataset of images. I would like to change the weights of the NN after each epoch. However, this is taking a long time as I use a loop on the model.fit as below:

```
 for t in range(100):
        hist=model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1,callbacks=callbackz) 
        weights0=model.layers[0].get_weights()
        weights1=model.layers[1].get_weights() 
        [ModifiedVector0,ModifiedVector1]=ModifyTheWeights(weights0,weights1) 
         model.layers[0].set_weights(ModifiedVector0)
         model.layers[1].set_weights(ModifiedVector1)
```

Is there an alternative way to modify the weights after each epoch without using a for loop? or is there any way to accelerate the running of the loop?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can use `on_epoch_end` in callback function to update weights.refer this  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean "without using a for loop", as the loop runs for the epochs, it is necessary, to improve slow code you should use a profiler, not do it blindly